# TinyMCE save source to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'm new in TinyMCE. I want to use it for editing several HTML files. Is it possible?

Example:
<kbd>file_to_edit.html</kbd>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Soft\TinyMCE\tinymce\js\tinymce\tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script>
      tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#mytextarea',
        mode: 'textareas',
        plugins: 'code, save',
        toolbar: 'code | save',
        save_enablewhendirty : true,
        save_onsavecallback: () => {
        },
        object_resizing: false
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Long attribute description</h1>
    <form>
      <textarea id="mytextarea">Attribute description</textarea>
      <h2>HTML output</h2>
    <div class="HTMLContainer"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Question**:
I want to change the text in `mytextarea` field by using `TinyMCE`

I tried several options but there was no result:

1. I added the "Save" plugin and tried to use "Save" toolbar button to save the text. But there was no reaction.
2. I added `tinymce.triggerSave()` method in `save_onsavecallback` lambda
3. I used `tinymce.activeEditor.save()` method
4. I tried to change the editor mode `tinymce.mode.set("design")`
5. `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()` and `tinymce.activeEditor.setContent()` methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out what's going on with the save feature, I've added a function and a button to to your example to try the setContent API method again.

Running the demo, pressing the save button does set the content in the editor, but then the page refreshes (I'm guessing that's because of the save options enabled - hopefully that's the goal here).

I also removed the whitespace between `save_enablewhendirty` and the `:` which may have also been causing the errors and stopping the save working.

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#mytextarea',
        mode: 'textareas',
        plugins: 'code, save',
        toolbar: 'code | save',
        save_enablewhendirty: true,
        save_onsavecallback: () => {
        },
        object_resizing: false
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Long attribute description</h1>
    <form>
      <textarea id="mytextarea">Attribute description</textarea>
      <h2>HTML output</h2>
    <div class="HTMLContainer"></div>
    <button id='buttonS'>Save</button>
    </form>
  </body>
<script>
    function saveEditor() {
        tinymce.get("mytextarea").setContent("<p>Content set!</p>");
      }
    var buttonLine = document.getElementById('buttonS');
    buttonLine.addEventListener('click', saveEditor, false);
</script>
</html>
```

There is also some content available on setting up the save plugin with node.js for testing out saving editor contents with something close to what might happen in production: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/set-up-the-tinymce-save-plugin/

Comment: It works! Actually, I had to finalize the code. I also add the function of loading. But after all it works. Thank you!